# How to avoid elements overlapping showing softkeyboard on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-xml, android-scrollview

I've read a lot of posts here and can't seem to find how to do it.

I'm trying to create the following layout xml.

In the middle I want a `LinearLayout` with some buttons inside and between the top and the beginning of the `LinearLayout` I want a `textView`.

The **LinearLayout** is inside a **ScrollView** that is inside a **RelativeLayout**

I achieved this by putting the `LinearLayout` and `TextView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. The `LinearLayout` is in the center of the parent and the `textView` is above the `linearLayout` and to the top of the parent. The text is centered vertically.

The problem is when the `keyboard` is on. I placed only the `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.
If I use `adjustPan` in the `manifest` then nothing happens and I can't `scroll`. If I use `adjustResize` then the `Textview` appears on top of the `LinearLayout` and not above. How can I do it then? Or is it not possible?
I just want the `linearLayout` to be `scrollable` if needed.
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mLayout">

            <Button
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Match"
                android:id="@+id/btn_newMatch"
                style="@style/ButtonBar"
                android:typeface="monospace"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Manage Matches"
                android:id="@+id/btn_manageMatches"
                style="@style/ButtonBar"
                android:typeface="monospace"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Manage Teams"
                android:id="@+id/btn_manageTeams"
                style="@style/ButtonBar"
                android:typeface="monospace"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
                style="@style/ButtonBar"
                android:typeface="monospace"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logout"
                android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
                style="@style/ButtonBar"
                android:typeface="monospace"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_above="@id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMediumInverse"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it currently looks with adjustResize:

Without keyboard:

[image]

With Keyboard:

[image]

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thx!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

just add this

> `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"`

to at your activity declaration in your manifest .

Comment: With the adjustPan the screen doesn't resize. The keyboard stays on top of the layout so the layout doesn't overlap but it doesn't scroll either.

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem..! what you want exactly?

Comment: What I really want is for the layout to resize to a minimum height where nothing gets overlapped and become scrollable. But after reading a lot I don´t think this is possible. So I would want it to be scrollable to avoid the overlapping that I showed on the images.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_newMatch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="New Match"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_manageMatches"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Manage Matches"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_manageTeams"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Manage Teams"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logout"
                android:typeface="monospace" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**At your Manifest in activity tag**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent vertical overlap of views in my `RelativeLayout` when the keyboard gets shown - simply adding a margin solved the problem

`android:layout_marginTop="25dp"`